# Store doesn't fire changes to the async pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

In my app.component.html I create a custom component (contact-table component) that should get a new value (Account) to present after I update the in the store the connected user to be someone else.

app.component.html:

```
<contact-table [contacts]="connectedAccount$ |async"></contact-table>
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit
{
  private connectedAccount$: Observable<Account>;
  constructor(private store:Store<any>) {
    this.connectedAccount$ = this.store
      .select(state=> state.connectedAccountReducer.connectedAccount);

    this.connectedAccount$
      .subscribe(account1=> {
       //the app prints any new account that comes up. It's working here.
       console.log(account1);
      });
  }
  public ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch({
      type: updateConnectedAccount,
      payload: {
        connectedAccount: ACCOUNTS[0]
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The subscribtion in AppComponent class works great and fires any update that comes up.

The problem is that the async pipe in app.component.html does not send the new account to the contact-table component. I think he doesn't get notified for any updates.

I tried to see what is being sent to the contact-table component,
and I saw he only get one value in the first creation of the contact-table component and its undefined. Thats not possibole becouse my reducer function creates an empty Account object for the initial state of my app.

Is there anything you notice that I missed?

Comment: What does your contact-table component look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the json pipe just to see if the view is getting anything from that store select.

`<span>{{connectedAccount$ |async | json}}</span>`

Comment: I saw your other post asking about the select. I don't yet have enough rep in stackoverflow to comment there.  I just wanted to recommend that you check out these examples if you haven't already seen them to help when figuring out setup.
https://github.com/ngrx/example-app  and  https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-examples .  Both have given me ideas for my current project.

Answer (score 2):

Check and make sure you are using Object.assign to create the changes to your state.  It shouldn't return a mutated state. Redux/ngrx and the async pipe detect changes when the object hash changes (or at least this is my understanding).  I've run into this problem when I wasn't creating a brand new object but accidentally mutating the existing state and returning it.

To quote the redux site -> http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

> We don’t mutate the state. We create a copy with Object.assign(). Object.assign(state, { visibilityFilter: action.filter }) is also wrong: it will mutate the first argument. You must supply an empty object as the first parameter. You can also enable the object spread operator proposal to write { >...state, ...newState } instead.

I also had a async issue with RC2 so if you aren't using RC3 or above I'd recommend upgrading.

Not saying this is it but it is the most likely candidate from my experience.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Also I'd highly recommend using the ngrx-store-logger during development.  It will write out the the state to the console before and after a action and it will also print out the action in between.

https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-logger

Comment: Okay first of all thanks for the answer! For each change in the object, store does return the new state into the subscribe inside the AppComponent class as mentioned. I can't understand why the changes being sent to there but not to the async pipe also. All in all, I will take the tips you mentions + will start to use ngrx-store-logger. Any other solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can include [ngrx-store-freeze](https://github.com/codewareio/ngrx-store-freeze) - the problem with mutable state is easy to address.
Another way of how I often debug the dispatching of **Actions** is to introduce an Effect for logging purpose. This helps to identify problems as well.